# Convert String to Integer without using atoi

Tags: c, string, integer

How would I convert string to integer without using atoi from arguments given? Here's what I've tried:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++){
        const char *p = argv[i];
        int j = 0;
        while(isdigit(*p)){
            j = j * 10 + *p - '0';
            p++;
            printf("%d\n", j);
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, it's splitting apart and re-adding them again.

```
$ ./a.out 55 6 50 66
5
55
6
5
50
6
66
```

Comment: `printf("%d\n", j);` move to after while-loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're printing all the intermediate results. Save the printout until after you've completed the while loop.

```
while(isdigit(*p)){
    j = j * 10 + *p - '0';
    p++;
}

printf("%d\n", j);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    //char name[1000];
    //cin>>name;
    char name[]="123456";

    int data, result, output,Base;
    //volatile int Base;
    //int Base;
    data=1; result=0; Base=strlen(name);
    while (Base>= 1)
    {
        Base--;
        output=toascii(name[Base])-48;
        output=output*data;
        result= result+output;
        data=data*10;
    }
    std::cout<<"this is the string you enterd"<<name<<"integer is"<<result;

    return 0;
}
```