# how can I convert character to integer number

Tags: c++, c

How could I change an array of character (string) to an integer number without using any ready function (ex atoi();) for example :-

```
 char a[5]='4534';
```

I want the number 4534 , How can I get it ?

Comment: without using atoi? Implement our own atoi.

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25776715/convert-string-to-integer-without-using-atoi

Comment: First, you have to start with a string: `a[5] = "4534"`. Strings are enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: Only `atoi` is not allowed or any standard function ?

Comment: @RaghuSrikanthReddy The problem I don't understand the idea how to do it :)

Comment: @ameyCU  any other standard function not allowed also

Comment: See also: `sscanf` and `std::istringstream`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I thought of same but OP don't want any standard function .

Comment: @ThomasMatthews they are not allowed to use

Comment: @codemonster Hint: `'4' - '0'` gives you a single digits numerical value. With this in mind, the rest should be easy.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  the problem that I was facing is how can I do it if I have more than a single digit.

Comment: @codemonster Well `4 * 1000 + 5 * 100 + ...`

Comment: WHY 2 UPVOTES? This question must have a dozen of duplicates.............................................................................................................................

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without using any existing libraries, you have to:

1. Convert character to numeric digit.
2. Combine digits to form a number.

Converting character to digit:

```
digit = character - '0';
```

Forming a number:

```
number = 0;
Loop:
number = number * 10 + digit;
```

Your function will have to check for '+' and '-' and other non-digits characters.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, now I understand how to do it :)

Comment: If the answer is useful, please click on the check mark.

Answer (score 1):

First of all this statement

```
 char a[5]='4534';
```

will not compile.  I think you mean

```
 char a[5]="4534";
           ^^   ^^
```

To convert this string to a number is enough simple.

For example

```
int number = 0;

for ( const char *p = a; *p >= '0' && *p <= '9'; ++p )
{
    number = 10 * number + *p - '0';
}
```

Or you could skip leading white spaces.

For example

```
int number = 0;

const char *p = s;

while ( std::isspace( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) ++p;

for ( ; *p >= '0' && *p <= '9'; ++p )
{
    number = 10 * number + *p - '0';
}
```

If the string may contain sign '+' or '-' then you can check at first whether the first character is a sign.

Answer (score 0):

You can go like this

It's working

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{

  char a[5] = "4534";

  int converted = 0;

  int arraysize = strlen(a);

  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < arraysize ; i++)
  {
    converted = converted *10 + a[i] - '0';
  }

  printf("converted= %d", converted);   

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no [`pow` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) that returns an integer.  There could be floating point conversion issues.  A safer method is multiply the previous value by 10, see my answer.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews, you were right, I did the correction

Answer (score -2):

I prefer to use the `std::atoi()` function to convert string into a number data type. In your example you have an **non-zero terminated array** `"\0"`, so the function will not work with this code.

Consider to use **zero** terminated `"strings",` like:

```
char *a = "4534";

int mynumber = std::atoi( a );   // mynumber = 4534
```

Comment: First of all, `atoi` is broken and should not be used, unless you can live with the fact that `"0"` cannot be distinguished from invalid input. The C++11 function `std::stoi` should be used instead (and before C++11, string streams). Second, the OP's example is broken because `'4534'` is not at all the same as `"4534"`. Third, your `char*` should be a `char const *`.

Comment: yes I know how to use it, but it's not allowed to use it in my code. :)

Comment: Please take a look at my post again, where the use of std::atoi is showed, before minusing it!

Your second point is explained too in my post!

Can you give me a reason why it should be a const char* to demonstrate std::atoi()?

Comment: @ViktorLiehr: A string literal consists of **unmodifiable** characters. You cannot point to `const` objects with a non-`const` pointer. You might even receive a compiler warning for this. And the attempt to modify something which is unmodifiable results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: @ViktorLiehr: Consider also what would happen if the string literal was `"0"`, and then consider what would happen if it was `"x"`. Now try to write an `atoi` program which responds differently to both.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Of course I can point to const data with a non-const pointer without changing them.

If you don't believe me, believe your eyes: http://cpp.sh/5hth

Second point: Yes, on both cases std::atoi() will return 0. Knowing the restrictios of std::atoi() it is an easy part to do an check before calling it.

So, what is your point?

Comment: @ViktorLiehr: Turn on all warnings and you will see that you get a warning about a deprecated conversion. So, yes, my wording should have been a bit different. It's disallowed in all cases except of string literals, for which it is "only" bad practice. Of course, `a[0] = '1';` can still crash your program. Regarding `atoi`, my point is that the check is not at all "easy" but is instead so complicated that checking the input's validity almost includes the entire conversion process. How do you think that "easy" part would work, precisely?

Comment: @ChristianHackl: What are you talking about? An IsNumeric() is not "easy", it is complicated? You are missing the point, the question was, how to convert a character into an integer! I'm still missing your point.

Comment: @ViktorLiehr: Yes, an `IsNumeric` is quite complicated if you consider all corner cases. Here are some of them: `IsNumeric("10.1")`, `IsNumeric("-1")`, `IsNumeric("+1")`, `IsNumeric(".0")`, `IsNumeric("100000000000000000000000000000")`, `IsNumeric("10,1")`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: So your question is, how to distinguish between floating point and non floating point?

Comment: @ViktorLiehr: That's only a subset of all problems. Consider the `"+1"` or `"-1"` cases. Or what about `" 1"`? Still, even `"1.1"` is interesting. `atoi` would turn it into 1, so your `IsNumeric` has to accept it. But then again, even something like `"1x1"` would become 1, as would `" 1x1"`. Do you still think that such checks are easy to write and prove to be correct? All because `atoi` has no suitable error-reporting mechanism. Not to mention the fact that passing it numbers that are too high or too low results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Can you please look at the example again. The demo value is "4534", so it is a non floating point the user wants to convert. Otherwise it is not mentioned in the question! Why do you think my IsNummeric() function will accept the value without knowing my implemenation? I guess you are missing the point again, IsNummeric() is an proposal to validate, that the incomming string is suiteable for std::atoi().

Comment: @ViktorLiehr: That the demo value is `"4532"` is quite irrelevant if you are looking for a general solution. Otherwise, the most direct "solution" would be `int number = 4534;`. And you are still missing my point: `atoi` requires extremely complicated security checks before you can use it, practically making it useless, especially in C++, where you have safe alternatives.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: On the opposite, it was not asked for a general solution, otherwise the user should mention it in the question. Do you agree? No question that std::atoi has its limitations, and a check has to be done before it is called.

What is your propoal to use instead of std::atoi() ?

Comment: @ViktorLiehr: `std::stoi` or `std::istringstream`.